# How to put String names out of list to new String in pythonic way

Tags: python

I want to add all strings from a list to new String with a special format in Pythonic way:

I have a List with [ 'Module1', 'Module2', 'Module3']
The new string variable should look like = 'Hello, i found ' + 'Module1, Module2, Module3' + ' in your list'

How can i implement this?

My approuch whould be:

```
    moduleNames = ""
    for item in notFinishedModules:
      moduleNames = moduleNames + item + ", "
    moduleNames = moduleNames[:-2]
    like = 'Hello, i found ' + moduleNames + ' in your list'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
like = 'Hello, i found {} in your list'.format(', '.join(notFinishedModules))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use join:

```
like = 'Hello, i found ' + ', '.join(notFinishedModules) + ' in your list'
```

Comment: Good answer, but @eumiro's version is a bit more "pythonic" :)

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join , this makes a string of the module names, you can choose the delimiter etc.